# c# combine dictionary values into new key value pair

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

I have a c# dictionary like this:

[image]

what I need to do is combine the values where Dictionary keys contains "UPC" into a new key with combined values so it reads like this:
{[UPC, 000000000333, 789787878999]}

The UPCs could contain one or more values.

I came up with the code below to remove possible duplicates from a information dictionary first

[image]

```
//Remove any duplicates
        List<string> vals = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in information)
        {
            if (!vals.Contains(item.Value))
            {
                newDict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                vals.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sbUPC = new StringBuilder();
        
        var newDictJustUPCs = newDict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains("UPC"));
```

The newDictJustUPCs returns the following:

[image]

So how would I loop thru these KeyValuePairs and create the KeyValue pair for newDict having the key "UPC" and the two values combined and assign it to newDict?

I know part of the final answer will be newDict.Add("UPC", CombinedUPCValues);

Answer (score 1):

There are simply oodles of ways you can do this. Here is just one

**Given**

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "asd", "dfgdfg" },
   { "ghj", "ghj" },
   { "UPC1", "123" },
   { "UPC2", "345" },
   { "UPC3", "567" }
};
```

**Usage**

```
var upc = dict
   .Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("UPC"))
   .Select(x => x.Value);

var newDict = dict
   .Where(x => !x.Key.StartsWith("UPC"))
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

newDict.Add("UPC", string.Join(",", upc));


foreach (var item in newDict)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " : "+ item.Value);
```

**Output**

```
asd : dfgdfg
ghj : ghj
UPC : 123,345,567
```

Answer (score 1):

First Extract out all UPC elements and create its value as you want and then append it to new array that dont have UPC elements

```
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Modified by", "Stuart gill" },
            {"Modified on", "11/2/2021" },
            {"UPC0", "000000000333" },
            {"UPC2", "789789789" },
        };

       var keyValueWithUpc = dict.Where(kv => kv.Key.StartsWith("UPC")).ToArray();
       var upcValue = string.Join(",", keyValueWithUpc.Select(kv => kv.Value));
       var result = dict.Except(keyValueWithUpc)
                         .Append(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UPC", upcValue))
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Append method: It takes source (collection to append) an array instead of one , just to distinguish from existing one , but since it takes as an params you can also pass single item

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] itemsToAppend)
    {
        return source.Concat(itemsToAppend);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried out your recommendation and on the .Append it indicated Compiler Error CS1061 for the IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> 

'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist.

Comment: Its available in Enumerable class , for .Net5.0  . You can create your own like edited answer

Answer (score 0):

TheGeneral pointed me in the right direction with his code example. Here was my solution. Below log information is passed in.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Dictionary<string, string> information = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        List<string> changes = log.Changes.ToString().Split('?').ToList();
        changes.RemoveAt(changes.Count - 1);
        
        int start = 0;
        
        foreach (string units in changes)
        {
            string[] unit = units.Split('|');
            string[] parts = unit[0].Split('-');
            string[] values = unit[1].Split('^');

            string field = parts[1];
            string orig = values[0];
            
            if (unit[0] == "VendorPartUpc-UPC")
            {
                information.Add(field+start, values[1]);
                start = start + 1;
            }
            else if (values.Count() > 1 && (orig != string.Empty || values[1] != string.Empty) && !information.ContainsKey(field))
                information.Add(field, values[1]);
        }

        //Remove any duplicates
        List<string> vals = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in information)
        {
            if (!vals.Contains(item.Value))
            {
                newDict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
                vals.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }
        
        //Need to take the UPCs from multiple key/value pairs, extract just the UPC value and put into a single value with UPC as the key.
        var newDictJustUPCs = newDict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains("UPC"));
        var upc = newDictJustUPCs
            .Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("UPC"))
            .Select(x => x.Value);

        newDict.Add("UPC", string.Join(",", upc));
         
        information = newDict;

        return information;
```